# Ошибка 404 при переходе на страницу сайта в ASP

Tags: iis, asp.net-webforms, http-status-code-404

Здравствуйте.

Я пытаюсь опубликовать сайт на сервере (Windows Server 2008 R2) с использованием IIS (версии 7.5). Сам сайт писал на ASP.NET с версией .NET 4.5, и включил в нем поддержку Windows-авторизации.

При запуске сайта на локальной машине из Visual Studio - все работает отлично, на все страницы переходит и все работает. Однако, при публикации сайта в IIS у меня заходит только на стандартную Default.aspx страницу и при попытке перехода на другие страницы (даже на "Контакты") мне выдает ошибку, и не важно захожу ли я на сервер или запускаю браузер прямо на сервере:

> Ошибка HTTP 404.0 - Not Found Разыскиваемый вами ресурс был удален,
>   было изменено его имя или он временно недоступен.
>
> Запрашиваемый URL-адрес http://localhost:80/sitename/Contact
>
> Физический путь C:\IIS_Apps\sitenameASP\wwwroot\sitename\Contact
>
> Способ входа Negotiate
>   Пользователь, выполнивший вход
>   OFFICE\igutnikov

Проверка подлинности Windows в IIS включена и работает - идет запрос при заходе на сайт, анонимная проверка подлинности выключена. У папки, в которой хранится сайт и его страницы все права есть.

В чем может быть проблема? Как ее решить?

=============================================================

UPD: Нашел решение - нужно в глобальный Web.config добавить:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="BundleModule" />
  <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
</modules>
```

Comment: а приложение в папке sitename создано? правой кнопкой по папке в IIS Manager / Convert to application.

Comment: @PashaPash добавлял через "Добавить приложение...", так что по-идее создано.

Comment: Решение проблемы нашел здесь: http://blog.cdeutsch.com/2012/11/fixing-404-errors-for-aspnet-mvc-apps.html

Comment: это дико кривое решение - оно начинает проводить через managed code вообще все запросы, включая запросы к статическим файлам. с extensionless url есть пара стандартных проблем, сейчас попробую написать ответ со списком фиксов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько стандартных причин, по которым может не работать extensionless urls - ссылки без расширений.

1. У вас криво поставлен .net. Решается вызовом

   ```
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -r
   ```
2. Не хватает станадртных апдейтов (актуально для Windows Server до 2012). Решается установкой https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/980368.
3. IIS был доставлен в систему после .NET. В принципе, решается (1), но можно попробовать решение с включением одной из фич в Add Remove Windows Features:

   - Internet Information Services --> World Wide Web Services --> Common HTTP Features --> HTTP Error Redirection
   - Internet Information Services --> World Wide Web Services --> Performance Features --> Static Content Compression

   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2023146

---

Костыль с `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` встречается часто, но его не стоит использовать на реальных серверах. Он приводит именно к тому, что написано в названии опции - вообще все запросы начинают проходить через managed modules. Т.е., например проверка куки с тикетом Forms Auth будет происходить вообще на всех запросах, включая картинки, css, скрипты и favicon, что приводит к 
потенциальным проблемам с производительностью.